# Laravel Eloquent Multiple Column IN Clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have recently started to develop using Laravel, and my first project is a vehicle booking application.

I seem to be doing fine, however I am stuck trying to show current bookings using Eloquent.

The system works by adding vehicles to the `vehicles` table, and employees to the `employees` table. A many-to-many relationship with a pivot table is created using `employee_vehicle`.

**employees**

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| surname    | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**vehicles**

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| registration | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| make         | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| model        | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**employee_vehicle**

```
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| employee_id | int(10)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vehicle_id  | int(10)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| direction   | varchar(3) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_booked | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| damaged     | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mileage     | int(10)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Result**

```
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
| id | employee_id | vehicle_id | direction | date_booked         | damaged | mileage |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|  1 |           1 |          1 | OUT       | 2016-06-13 09:08:08 |       0 |    2357 |
|  2 |           1 |          1 | IN        | 2016-06-16 16:29:26 |       0 |    2401 |
|  3 |           2 |          1 | OUT       | 2016-06-20 10:47:28 |       0 |    2470 |
|  4 |           3 |          2 | OUT       | 2016-06-14 09:18:52 |       0 |    1403 |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

These tables have `Vehicle` and `Employee` models that extend Eloquent. These have methods which call `belongsToMany`.

What I want to do is get the `Vehicle` collection and eager load the employees onto it. That way I can show currently booked vehicles, along with who currently has booked them out.

For example:

`$vehicleBookings = Vehicle::with(['employees'])->get();`

I shall explain the way that a booking works...

Basically, a vehicle and an employee are linked together using the pivot table. The table also records the date booked, the direction of the booking (e.g. Booked IN, or OUT), and additional data about its condition etc.

It is important that there is an entry for both IN and OUT so that there is an audit log of the vehicle condition before and after bookings.

The problem I had was to be able to get the latest state of a vehicle from its available bookings, as to determine whether it was currently booked out, or available to book. This determines what can be done with a vehicle.

After some research I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `employee_vehicle` 
WHERE (`vehicle_id`, `date_booked`) IN (
   SELECT `vehicle_id`, MAX(`date_booked`)
    FROM `employee_vehicle`
    GROUP BY `vehicle_id`
)
```

(I didn't even know it was possible to use multiple columns with an IN clause until now, but it's great!).

This gives me:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
| id | employee_id | vehicle_id | direction | date_booked         | damaged | mileage |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|  3 |           2 |          1 | OUT       | 2016-06-20 10:47:28 |       0 |    2470 |
|  4 |           3 |          2 | OUT       | 2016-06-14 09:18:52 |       0 |    1403 |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

This gives me one row per vehicle that has ever been booked (this is before joining any employees to it).

However now I am really stuck. I just cannot figure out how to write an equivalent query using Eloquent that also joins on the Employees. (It will also need to show only vehicles currently "OUT", but I guess that's the trivial part!)

I *could* just write the query using `DB::raw('...')`, and don't mind manually writing long SQL queries, however I *really* want to give it a go properly, trying to use Eloquent.

I have noticed the `whereIn` method, but it only accepts a string for one column name rather than an array of multiple columns, so this is a no-go. (Unless I am missing something, or it is planned for a future version of Laravel?)

I was never really a fan of frameworks, and have needed some convincing, and not wishing to be defeated, have stuck with Laravel. This is frustrating me as I feel that it would be quicker just to not mess around with Eloquent. If I can get this to work then I will be more accepting of it.

Comment: So You looking for to get employee_vehicle with employees and vehicles together?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The long answer is yes, but how do I write the query I posted _but_ using Eloquent that _also_ gets everything together. I don't know if I am explaining myself right.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say You've

Employee model:

```
class Employee extends Model {
  protected $table = 'employees';
  public $timestamps = false;
}
```

and Vehicle model:

```
class Vehicle extends Model {
  protected $table = 'employees';
  public $timestamps = false;
}
```

and You want to get latest logs grouped by vehicle_id.

So make a model:

```
class EmployeeVehicle extends Model {
  protected $table = 'employee_vehicle';
  public $timestamps = false;  

  public function employee() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
  }

  public function vehicle() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Vehicle');
  }
}
```

and You request to DB will be like:

```
$EmployeeVehicles = EmployeeVehicle::with(['employee', 'vehicle'])
                                  ->where('date_booked', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 3*30*24*60*60)))
                                  ->groupBy('vehicle_id')
                                  ->selectRaw('*, MAX(`date_booked`) AS `last_date_booked`')
                                  ->paginate(50);
```

p.s. I've added `where('date_booked', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 3*30*24*60*60))` because Your query to log database is very heavy job for database engine, and normally it's good to have data from past 3 month for performance safety.

And try to paginate, not to get everything.

Comment: Ahhh, so it's possible to make a pivot table into a model itself? Is this the standard/accepted way to do it? I'm all very new to this :).

Comment: Yes, of course! Eloquent is powerful. if You think a little different (Eloquentish way) (:

Comment: Bor me pivot table is table with 2 fields without id field: employee_id, vehicle_id   and pivot table also can be used as model. But keep in mind that employee_vehicle that You show us is not pivot table, it's more a "log" table (: